# Output layer's shape is always (1,)

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, shapes

I am trying to make a simple Keras model. But regardless of what output shape I am specifying the output layer is always of the shape `(1,)` so I cannot train my model because of the output layer and target data shapes mismatch.

```py
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import InputLayer, LSTM, Dense

# 63 is the number of unique characters
# 128 is the length of a sequence of characters

X = ... # X is an one-hot ndarray; X.shape == (96092, 128, 63)
Y = ... # Y is an one-hot ndarray; Y.shape == (96092, 63)

model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer([128, 63]))
model.add(LSTM(96))
model.add(Dense(63))

model.compile(
  optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(1e-3, decay=1e-5),
  loss=keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
)

model.fit(X, Y) # ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (63,)
```

As you can see, the shape of the output dense layer is `(1,)` but it has to be of shape `(63,)`. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Google Colab with preinstalled Keras.

Comment: What loss function are you using?

Comment: see the updated post with `model.compile` arguments shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that error is saying is that the shape of the output layer *is* 63. However, for some reason, it *expects* 1.

In this case, the reason it expects 1 is because you are using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, which expects an integer representing the index of the output category. Instead, use `categorical_crossentropy`, which expects a one-hot encoding of the output category.